# Integration Proof: Integration limits can be integrals with integration limits on them??!!

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi all I'm studying calculus for my self and I have a question about integrals and their upper and lower limits. The next integral can be possible and if it isn't possible explain with a demonstration why not. If this integral can be possible post the result. Any help and suggestion are strongly appreciated. This integral is an idea from my friend, he studies quantum and statistical physics, I don't have any idea that this is possible.

$$
\displaystyle\int\limits_{\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}}^{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}} \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}.
$$

Comment: Please use MathJax to format equations and make them more readable. Link here- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The idea of having integral expressions as limits is not problematic.  If the lower limit were $\int_0^1x\ dx$ you could evaluate that to $\frac 12$ and have the lower limit.  They do have to be well defined.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant to be rigorous, this is not possible.

See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F%281-x%5E2%29+from+-infty+to+infty  and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F%281-x%5E2%29+from+0+to+infty . Both show the upper and lower limit diverge. Hence this integral is not even well defined.

Unless you mean like, the upper and lower teds to infinity, (which your notation is not true) and we evalute the integral with these limit points.

Then we have several way to make sense of it, like if the integral in the limits are seen to differ only in a constant uniformly (not true, since their difference is actually the lower limit, which diverges), then you can compute the whole integral as limit of an integral over interval of costant length.

These interpretations can be given in advance. Which we can interpret your integral now as $\lim_{M\to \infty}\int\limits_{\int_0^M \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}}^{\int_{-M}^M \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}} \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}.$

Comment: The problem is not at infinity. The problem is at $-1$ and $1$. Look at your own links; they give Cauchy Principal values for each integral. Your proposed limit doesn’t fix this problem.

Comment: If we naively say $\int_a^bf^\prime(x)dx=f(b)-f(a)$ even if $f^\prime$'s behaviour somewhere in $[a,\,b]$ makes this unworkable for your favourite formal notion of integration, we can say $\frac12\ln|\frac{1+x}{1-x}|$ is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$, so the inetgral is $\int_0^0\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$F(x) = \int \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2} = \frac12\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) $$ 
(where we choose the constant of integration to be zero). Then $$\frac{1+x}{1-x} >0 \iff |x|<1, $$ so $F$ is only defined on $(-1,1)$. This means that integrals of the form $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2},\quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\mathsf dx}{1-x^2}$$ are not well-defined. So your example is not possible.

For an example that **is** possible, let $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$. Then $$F(x) = \int f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{Erf}(x)$$
(again choosing the constant of integration to be zero) is defined for all $x\in\mathbb R$, and 
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x) = -\frac{\sqrt\pi}2,\quad \lim_{x\to\infty}F(x) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2.
$$
It follows that
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) - F(0) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2,
$$
and similarly
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) - \lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x) = \frac{\sqrt\pi}2 - -\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right)=\sqrt\pi.
$$
Hence
$$
\int_{\int_0^\infty f(x)\ \mathsf dx}^{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\ \mathsf dx} f(x)\ \mathsf dx = \int_{\frac{\sqrt\pi}2}^{\sqrt\pi} e^{-x^2}\ \mathsf dx
=  \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \left(  \operatorname{Erf}(\sqrt\pi) - \operatorname{Erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\right) \right)<\infty,
$$
so this integral is well-defined.

Comment: It seems to me the indefinite integral is perfectly well defined outside $[-1,1].$ It just isn’t defined at $-1$ or $1.$ The definite integrals shown are not well defined because $1$ is inside their intervals of integration.

Answer (score 0):

The awkward thing here isn't that you have integrals as the integration limits of your main integral.
As pointed out in a comment, as long as the definite integral at each limit converges when considered on its own, you can evaluate each of those integrals first, obtaining two numeric limits, and then evaluate the main integral between those limits (provided that the main integral converges on that interval).

What is awkward is that neither of the integrals at the integration limits converges in the standard sense.

The problem with the integrals is not what they do near their own integration limits, that is, near $-\infty,$ near $0$, or near $\infty$. It's what they do near $-1$ and $1.$

For example,
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-2} \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = 
\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = -\frac{\ln3}{2}\approx -0.54931$$
and
$$ \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \frac{\ln3}{2}\approx 0.54931$$

No trouble there. But

$$ \lim_{y\to -1^-} \int_{-2}^y \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx =
 \lim_{y\to 1^+} \int_y^2 \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = -\infty $$
and
$$ \lim_{y\to -1^+} \int_y^{1/2} \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx =
 \lim_{y\to 1^-} \int_{1/2}^y \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = \infty. $$

This makes it a dubious endeavor to integrate over an interval that includes either $-1$ or $1.$

If we cannot evaluate the limits of the integral, we cannot evaluate the integral.

But near $-1,$ the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is like $\frac{1}{2(x+1)},$
and near $1$ it is like $-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}.$
As long as $-1$ or $1$ occurs only in the interior of the interval of integration, not as one of the endpoints,
the integral of $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ has a Cauchy principal value.
If we take Cauchy principal values, then
$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\mathrm dx = 0. $$

Perhaps that's what your friend had in mind. Or perhaps he made some other interpretation of the integrals. Ask him.